Cannot access the media files in production via Nginx
I am trying to access the media files using Nginx.
The file exists in the directory: /usr/src/app/backend/media/profile/c4ebe33d-7da1-4a62-bb17-8da254d69b36, where the part profile/c4ebe33d-7da1-4a62-bb17-8da254d69b36 is created dynamically.
The media root is: /usr/src/app/backend/media.
I know the file exists cause I am able to see it in the container.
This is my nginx config:
proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=STATIC:10m inactive=7d use_temp_path=off;


upstream backend {
  server backend:8000;
}

upstream frontend {
  server frontend:3000;
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server;

  server_name _;

  server_tokens off;

  gzip on;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_comp_level 4;
  gzip_types text/css application/javascript image/svg+xml;

  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

  client_max_body_size 100M;

  location /_next/static {
    proxy_cache STATIC;
    proxy_pass http://frontend;
  }

  location /static {
    proxy_cache STATIC;
    proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control;
    proxy_cache_valid 60m;
    proxy_pass http://frontend;
  }

  location /media/ {
    autoindex on;
    alias /usr/src/app/backend/media/;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://frontend;
  }

  location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://backend;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  }
}

When trying to access the file I get 404. This is the link to file: http://localhost/media/profile/c4ebe33d-7da1-4a62-bb17-8da254d69b36/da258fe5-f57c-44d2-94cf-00bef250b86d.png
I tried modifying nginx, cause I think this is the reason, but without success.
